# Chrome 25: Empty style tag at the end of every page

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

First I started seeing this on the page I was working on, but now I open up ANY website in Chrome, and it's there:

[image]

Anybody know what this is? Doesn't seem to break anything, but I have OCD...

Comment: Interesting observation .. Will check it out - but has a hunch that if you add additional css it might include in this tag .. try it out .. i

Comment: Tried disabling your add-ons?

Comment: @j08691 you got it. Adblock Plus. Please make an answer so I can accept. Also this might be suitable for migration to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of plug-ins or extensions do you have installed (or even used to have) installed chrome? If your seeing this on every site you go it is something on your end.

Possible solutions: try disabling or uninstalling all chrome extensions. Or, if that doesn't work, nuke chrome and re-install. I've run into to this on firefox b4, but never chrome.

Comment: Here it was AdBlock, too (as in the comments to the question)